# Can a thermal paper spot provide an estimate of the laser beam diameter?

Tags: optics, laser

I tried to estimate the laser beam diameter using a thermal paper. The spot on the thermal paper is ~3mm ( around the value for different input energies 50mW to 400mW). While if I record the beam profile using a CCD (using sufficient neutral density filters), the beam diameter comes around ~7-8mm (FWHM). Could it be that CCD is more sensitive to the scattered/ diffused light around the fundamental beam and the beam is about 3mm ( as determined with the thermal paper)?

Comment: We routinely used 'burn paper' for a 4J/pulse 4ns pulsed Nd:YAG laser. Instead of stacked ND filters, have you considered using a pellicle to pick off a small portion of the beam to send to the CCD?

Comment: It all depends on what definition of spot size you use.  You don't tell us what you took the diameter as measured by the CCD is.   Scattered/diffused light is not the issue.   Another thing to keep in mind is that the thermal paper will have an intensity threshold.  The same size beam at different intensities will produce burn spots of different sizes.

Comment: @JonCuster I tried using wedge earlier to record the beam profile and measured the FWHM of the beam to be ~7mm as well.

Comment: @garyp Sorry for not providing the details in the first go. The measured diameter is the FWHM of the beam. Adding on to it, irrespective of the difference in the input pulse power, the spot size on the paper remains between 3-3.5mm whereas that measured after recording a beam profile using CCD is approximately double.